# NullPointerException on API 19 and not on API 23

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I get a NullPointerException error, by using my APP on a S4 mini with API19. On a S7 with API 23 everything is working fine. Why do i get this error on the older API?

Here is the error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                         Process: com.example.entwicklung1.designtestapp, PID: 32571
>                                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                               at
>   com.example.entwicklung1.designtestapp.NewsAdapter.getItemCount(NewsAdapter.java:64)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3170)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2782)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17331)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17331)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1079)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17331)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5376)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17331)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5376)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17331)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5376)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17331)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5376)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17331)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5376)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2548)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17331)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2279)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1393)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1592)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1251)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6540)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
>                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
>                                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>                                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I know there are so many Questions about NullPointerException but nothing solved my problem yet.

**Here is the code of the first displayed line:**

```
@Override
        public int getItemCount() {   return feedItems.size();    }


    And the FeedItem.class:

        public class FeedItem {
        String titel;
        String link;
        String description;
        String pubDate;
        String imgsrc;
        String category;
        String summary;

        public String getSummary() {     return summary;    }

        public void setSummary(String summary) {
            this.summary = summary;
        }

        public String getCategory() {     return category;    }

        public void setCategory(String category) {  this.category = category;  }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getImgsrc() {
            return imgsrc;
        }

        public void setImgsrc(String imgsrc) {
            this.imgsrc = imgsrc;
        }

        public String getLink() {
            return link;
        }

        public void setLink(String link) {
            this.link = link;
        }

        public String getPubDate() {
            return pubDate;
        }

        public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
            this.pubDate = pubDate;
        }

        public String getTitel() {
            return titel;
        }

        public void setTitel(String titel) {
            this.titel = titel;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is fooditems arraylist or whatever it is, initialized inside onCreate?

Comment: Can you try cleaning your project then rebuild?

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding dont help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check when arraylist empty or not set your adapter.

```
if(!list.isEmpty())
{
 CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter();
}
```

Or

```
@Override
 public int getItemCount() {
     return (list == null) ? 0 : list.size();
 }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. This helped a bit, because i dont get the error anymore but nothing is displayed now. (Still only by unsing API19)